# ScheduledExecutorService android doesn't work on boot

Tags: java, android

I want to launch a `ScheduledExecutorService` on boot for checking my database all days.
I should launch this service at boot because if user doesn't launch the app this service couldn't work.

So when I launch my `ScheduledExecutorService` when app started it's okay but on boot `ScheduledExecutorService` seems not to work.

The `BroadcastReceive` on boot is working.

This is my code

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Ca passe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.e("sc", "Ca passe");    
                Toast.makeText(context,"scheduler fonctionne", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
            }
        },10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the documentation. Especially the documentation on the [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) lifecycle:

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.
>
> This has important repercussions to what you can do in an onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: anything that requires asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation completes.
>
> In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from within a BroadcastReceiver. For the former, you should instead use the NotificationManager API. For the latter, you can use Context.startService() to send a command to the service.

If you need to use an `Executor`, host it in an actual Android [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Otherwise, consider using [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to wake up your `Service`.